# Spring AMQP OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am running to this issue where JVM is running OutOfMemory and queue is getting stuck as a result container is restarting frequently. Even though I have exception handler in queue listener it is not working.

This is my application.properties

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.concurrency=3
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.max-concurrency=10
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.idle-event-interval=60000
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.prefetch1
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-attempts=1
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.default-requeue-rejected=false
```

and this is my listener

```
@RabbitListener(
    bindings = @QueueBinding(
        value = @Queue(value = "queue", durable = "true"),
        exchange = @Exchange(value = "exchange", type = ExchangeTypes.TOPIC),
        key = RabbitConfiguration.RULE_SERVICE_ROUTING_KEY
    )
)
public void processMessage(final Order order, final Message message) {

    try {

        // OutOfMemory is happening inside this service which calls Drools  
        this.service.run(order);      

    } catch (Throwable throwable) {

        logger.info("Message failed");
        throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(throwable);
    }
}
```

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-4"
```

Service code

```
public void run(Order order) {

    try {

        kieSession = this.getContainer(group, artifact, version).newKieSession();
        this.setUpListeners(kieSession);
        kieSession.insert(order);
        kieSession.fireAllRules();

    } catch (Throwables t) {

       throw new Exception(t);

    } finally {

        kieSession.dispose();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to reject this message and put it in dead letter queue.

Comment: Can you post the service class with run method? Asking because you wrote *"OutOfMemory is happening inside this service"*.

Comment: Sure I added that in the question.

Comment: When you are adding listener in `this.setUpListeners(kieSession);`, are you ever removing that from the collection? Perhaps that list/set/whatever of listeners is getting filled but never cleared?

Comment: Yes I am removing that listeners.

Comment: Well then try taking heap dumps to see which variable is getting filled up that's causing memory leak.

Comment: Exactly what does this have to do with Spring or RabbitMQ if the OOM is happening in your listener code?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is that if OutOfMemory happens I would like message to be kicked out to DLQ for the time being.